# Define Bean in combination with @ConditionalOnMissingBean does not work since Spring Boot Upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am using the Spring Boot Starter Version 2.0.8.RELEASE and try to upgrade to: 2.1.4.RELEASE.
I got the following error:

```
The bean 'defaultKafkaStreamsConfig', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/stream/configuration/StreamsConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

The Bean is defined as:

```
public class StreamsConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public StreamsConfig kStreamsConfigs(StreamsConfigFactory factory) {
        Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();
        addConfigurationProperties(additionalProperties);

        return factory.build(additionalProperties);
    }
}
```

The bean in the Spring Kafka Library has the annotation: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`.

I tried it already by annotate my Bean with: `@AutoConfigureBefore` and `@Primary`.

What was changed in Spring Boot, that the context loading now differs from versions before?

This is just an easy example, This happens on many parts in my code.

Btw.: I use already `@EnableAutoConfigure`.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.1 contains a new auto-configuration for Kafka Streams, see the release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#kafka-streams-support (I don't know if this already helps)

Comment: Not really. There is described, that overriding of beans is per default disabled. Spring already provides a config which is annotated with: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`. But this does not work. Maybe I have to enable Bean overriding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause.

I had to change the return type from `StreamsConfig` to `KafkaStreamsConfiguration`.

The Annotation: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` does not working, if the target class differs with its type from the already loaded bean.

The error message is misleading, because the message just mean the bean name and not the bean type.